# How can i print out a json Post parameter and save it to a variable using swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I saved json data as "posts " that contains a parameter(name) to a  tableView cell 
In this way :- 
**Cell.label.text = posts[indexpath.row].name**

But now i want to save it to a label instead of a tableView cell label
I tried :-
**label.text = posts.name**
But it didn't work ..can i get a solution on how to access the name parameter !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Alamofire

```
AF.request("\(URL)/posts").responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
                case let .success(value):
                if let posts = JSON(value)["posts"].array {
                    self.posts = posts
                }
                case let .failure(error):
                    print("\(error)")

                }
            }
```

And then in your table view cellForRowAt do the following:

```
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        let postName = post["name"].string
        cell.postNameLabel.text = postName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
    let postName = posts[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String ?? ""
    cell.label.text = postName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `posts` data is of type JSON array and that you want to populate a label outside of your TableView, if you need to access only the name property you would have to supply the index of the array as well.
Try something like `label.text = "\(posts[0].name)"` to print out the name of first element in array.

Comment: Assuming i dont have an array and im just receiveing  1 parameter .. how can i access it then ??

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by 1 parameter. Could you share some sample data and what is the expected content to be shown in the label, so that I can help you better?